# How to run same command in different containers?

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to execute the same command in several docker containers at once.

Run the command only to one container instance work:

```
sudo docker exec -it 0c3108d66666 mkdir newfolder && sudo touch newfile.txt
```

I want run the command specifying more containers ids or all, something similar to:

```
sudo docker exec -it 0c3108d666666 cf65935c7777 mkdir newfolder && sudo touch newfile.txt
```

This generate an error exec failed, I have searched and tried but nothing.

Comment: If you're trying to create the same file in a family of related containers, usually you'd do this by adding this to the corresponding image's `Dockerfile` and rebuilding it.

Answer (score 1):

Not only the [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) command take only *one* container parameter, but I don't even see an issue requesting that specific feature in [`moby/moby`](https://github.com/moby/moby/search?q=%22docker%20exec%22%20%22multiple%20containers%22&unscoped_q=%22docker%20exec%22%20%22multiple%20containers%22&type=Issues).

That means you would need to get the list of containers you want, loop over that list and call your `docker exec` command ([possibly in background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76719/7490), in order to launch them as parallel as possible)

Answer (score 1):

Obvious solution is a shell loop.  The tricky part is managing the exit code, which requires using a subshell:

```
(for container in 0c3108d666666 cf65935c7777; do
   sudo docker exec -it $container mkdir newfolder || exit;
 done) && sudo touch newfile.txt
```

You could also write a shell function to do this without a subshell, which may be more convenient for some uses.